# How to expire CSRF token intentionally in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, forms, csrf

I am using ajax request for form saving in Laravel, but I want to send ajax request only one time and them I want the CSRF to expire, so when visitor want to submit the form again he/she will not be able to send the request.

And when the page is refreshed again then the CSRF will work and can submit the form but only one time, after that the cycle will go on.

Comment: Your backend must keep track of the CSRF tokens that it issues (for example, by storing them in a database) and delete them after they have been used _once_.

Comment: I am not using database for storing CSRF tokens, is there any other way to expire the CSRF token after the form data is saved in controller function.

Comment: You can use the file system on the server instead, but somehow the server must keep track of which tokens it has already seen.

Comment: You should be able to just regenerate the session.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen 
so there is no a ready made solution available?

Comment: @Snapey so there is no a ready made solution available?

Comment: try `$request->session()->regenerate();`

Comment: @Snapey your answer work perfectly in my scenario. Thanks for your support.